# pack_forget generates strange flickering and does not completely hide the widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I get rid of the strange behavior of the `self.frame_control`, when I hover my mouse over the border of this widget I get an annoying flicker that I don't understand why it happens? Thank you very much.

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self._motion_1 = False
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = 100
        self.y1 = 0
        self.y2 = 50

        self.control = Frame(self, bg='green')
        self.control .pack(fill= 'both', expand= True)  

        self.lbl_change1 = Label(self.control, text='text 1', bg='black', fg='white', bd=0)
        self.lbl_change1   .pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand=True, padx=10)
        self.lbl_change2 = Label(self.control, text='text 2', bg='black', fg='white', bd=0)
        self.lbl_change2   .pack(side=LEFT, fill='both', expand=True, padx=10)
    
        #_______________
        self.master.bind('<Motion>',self.open_frame)
        self.master.bind('<Leave>', lambda arg: self.control .pack_forget())


    def open_frame(self, event):
        self.pointer_width_2  = event.x / self.master.winfo_width() * 100
        self.pointer_height_2 = event.y / self.master.winfo_height() * 100

        if not self._motion_1 == True:
            if self.x1 <(self.pointer_width_2)< self.x2  and  self.y1 <(self.pointer_height_2)< self.y2: 
                self.control .pack(fill= 'both', expand= True)
                print('if')
            else:
                print('else')
                self.control .pack_forget()
 
root = Tk()
root .geometry('200x600+300+0')
root .config(bg='gray22')
frame = Interface(root)
frame .pack()
root .mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you want to happen? what is the expected behavior?

Comment: there is an `'<Enter>'` event which is the opposite of `'<Leave>'` so you may want to use that

Comment: @Matiiss The problem with ```Enter``` is that I cannot select a specific part of the window to hide and show the widget, only if the mouse is positioned over this area should these statements be executed, ```x1,  x2, 
 y1,  y2``` sorry, I don't know if I make myself understood, I don't know if I'm using the correct terms. What I'm trying to do is show the widget if the mouse is over the top half of the window and hide it if it leaves this half or the window.

Comment: do you want to restrict to a specific area or a specific widget?

Comment: You need to check which widget triggers the event callbacks. I think you need to perform the task only when this event is triggered by `root` window.